# How to find the marker postion by its title?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a list where a user types and picks a place's name. The user clicks on the name and an infowindow pops up showing the location of the name.

I already have the markers made. I am able to get the title of the marker the user has clicked. How do I find the marker's position by the marker's title?

Here's the code for my

```
 // My list is pulled from an xml file
 String[] countries = getResources().
 getStringArray(R.array.list_of_countries);
 ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
 countries);
 actv = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
 actv.setAdapter(adapter);
 actv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {@
     Override
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView <? > parent, View view, int position,
     long id) {
     CharSequence country = ((TextView) view).getText();
     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), country, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
         .show(); // Here I get the marker's title.
   // for example if the title is "EF", how do I find that the LatLng = 23,82

 }
 });
```

Here's my markers:

```
  googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(23,81)).title("AB"));
  googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(24,81)).title("CD"));
  googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(23,82)).title("EF"));
```

Comment: Are you using a custom adapter to fill that list? Show us some of your code.

Comment: @Jonas452 Should I add more?

Answer (score 0):

You have the `title` and you said you already had the markers. You can perform a string search, assuming you have the markers in a list called markerList

```
LatLng l;
for(Marker m:markerList){
    if(m.getTitle.equals(title)){
        l=m.getPosition();
    }
}
```

There might be a more elegant way of achieving this but this is what I've been using.

**Update:** If those are your markers, consider keeping them in a list or something like that, a `HashMap` of (title,position) elements for instance. That way, you can add them to the map easier as well.

Answer (score 0):

As 0x5f3759df shows in his answer, you have to loop through the markers and search for them.  The problem is there is no constructor for the Marker class so you don't create them and then add them to the map, they are created as you add them to the map.  The other problem is there is no way to get the markers from the map after you have added them.  If you look at the addMarker method, it returns the marker as it adds it to the map, so the trick is to store a reference to what is returned by the addMarker method.

So what you need to do is something like this

```
ArrayList<Marker> mapMarkers = new ArrayList<Marker>();
```

then as you add them to the map add them to your arraylist

so again something like this

```
mapMarkers.add(googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(23,81)).title("AB")));
```

then you can use a loop to find the marker by title, or any other attribute.

```
Marker found = null;
for (Marker m : mapMarkers) {
   if (whatever) found = m;
}
if (found != null) doSomething();
```